# How to display every photo from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to display all photos from the database added by user X. The problem is that it only displays the first match. I added a foreach loop in html but it displays an error like photo.jpg

> Warning: foreach () argument must be of type array | object, null given in C:

```php
<?php

class photo_display
{
    private $database;
    private $userData;

    public function __construct($database)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function display()
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];

        $query = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT photo FROM photo where user_id = :id");
        $query->bindParam(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowcount())
        {
            $row = $query->fetch();
        }
        $this->userData = $row;

    }

    public function display_Photos(string $colName)
    {
        echo (isset($this->userData[$colName])) ? $this->userData[$colName] : '';
    }
}

?>
```

```html
 <div class='container-fluid bg-dark' id='profil'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class=" col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 order-5 order-12 order-6 order-md-4">
                    <div class="row" id="margin">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <?php foreach ($photo_display->display_Photos('photo') as $value){ echo var_dump($value); } ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo ($value) ;?>" alt="photo"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Maybe because`display_Photos` doesn't return anything.... ?!

Comment: According docs [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method fetches the next row from a result set - that means it get only one row. Try [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `echo` try to use `return`, then if is not isset return empty array `[]`

```
 public function display_Photos(string $colName)
    {
        return (isset($this->userData[$colName])) ? $this->userData[$colName] : [];
    }
```

Also as other suggested, you need to use fetchAll for set multiple row and not just one like:

```
if($query->rowcount())
  {
     $row = $query->fetchAll();
  }
```

Link:

- [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
- [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
- [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230323/discussion-on-answer-by-simone-rossaini-how-to-display-every-photo-from-a-databa).